# ファイルを予め指定した複数ディレクトリへ上書きコピーしたい

Tags: shellscript, unix, sh

**CentOS環境で、shファイルを実行したら、指定ファイルを、予め指定した複数ディレクトリへ上書きコピーしたいのですが、どう書けば良いでしょうか？**

---

**具体例**
・hoge.shを実行したら、z.jsを予め指定した「/var/www/a/」と「/var/www/b/」ディレクトリ直下へ配置したい
・その際、z.jsが既に存在してる場合は、上書き配置したい

**hoge.sh**

```
ary = ['/var/www/a/','/var/www/b/']
for((i=0;i<ary.size;i++))
do
   cp -fa z.js  ary[i]/z.js
done
```

Comment: 提示されたコードはshの書式ではないと思うので、擬似コードや他の言語であるならばその旨を明記された方がよいと思います。

Comment: 単にコピーをするだけなら`cp`コマンドを並べるだけでも済むはずなので、「何が分からないのか」困りごとを具体的に書いてください（例：ループを使って簡略化するには？など）。そもそも`sh`スクリプトの書き方が分からないのであれば、要件定義だけして「代わりに書いてください」という印象を与えます。

Comment: 配列部分は擬似コードですが、shのfor文はカッコを二重にするものと思っていました…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sh
#!/bin/sh
dirs=("/var/www/a" "/var/www/b")

for dest in "${dirs[@]}"
do
    cp -fa z.js $dest/z.js
done
```

Comment: 実行したら「cp: cannot create regular file `{dirs[@]}/z.js': そのようなファイルやディレクトリはありません」となりました

Comment: `for`文の記述が間違っていたので修正しました。

Comment: sh実行したら、期待した通り動作しました

Answer (score 1):

`for`を使わない回答例です。

```
#!/bin/bash
set -Cu
#set -vx # Uncomment for debugging

readonly DESTS=("/var/www/a/" "/var/www/b/")
readonly SOURCE="z.js"

# 存在チェックが必要なら
#{ echo "${DESTS[@]}" | tr " " "\n" | xargs -I@ sh -c 'test -d "$1" || { echo "$1 is not exists!" && exit 1; }' _ @; } || exit 1
echo "${DESTS[@]}" | tr " " "\n" | xargs -I@ cp --force --archive "$SOURCE" @ 

exit $?
```

shebangが`/bin/bash`なのは`TARGETS`を設定するときに配列を使うほうが見た目に分かりやすいかなと思ったからです。
なので`TARGETS="/var/www/a/ /var/www/b/"`でも構わないなら`/bin/sh`で動きます。

Comment: 期待した通り動作したのですが、内容難しかったです。「set -Cu」はどういう意味ですか？ Cオプションは、出力リダイレクトを禁じる？

Comment: @re9 `set -C`は`>`や`>&`などを使ってリダイレクトしたときに**既存のファイルを**上書きしなくなります。`set -u`は設定されていない変数やパラメーターを使おうとするとエラーになります。合わせて`set -Cu`をシェルスクリプトを作るときには最初に書いておくことにしています。

Comment: なるほど。お約束的意味合いで書いているわけですね。参考になりました

Answer (score 0):

配列より変数に入れた単語のリストのほうがより簡素で自然かなと思います。

```
#!/bin/sh
LIST="/var/www/a/ /var/www/b/"
for d in $LIST
do
   cp -fa z.js $d/z.js
done
```

Comment: これだとパスに空白文字が含まれているときにうまく動かないのではないでしょうか。

Comment: そうですね。空白が入ってるとうまく動作しませんのでエスケープするなどの対応が必要です。配列はbashの機能なのでこの回答はより「古いスタイル」で書かれた 別解だと思っていただければと思います。